# How to work with multiple repositories of same project root in a workspace?

Tags: maven, gradle, build, ant, developer-tools

I want to work on multiple repositories of the same project in a single project directory. How do I go about doing this effectively? Are there any build/project management tool to go about doing this?

For example, consider the workspace project structure:

```
/ProjectWorkspace/
    |-> build/(build artifacts of Application, ApplicationInterface, ForkedExternalDependency)
    |-> logs/
    |-> src/
        |-> Application/
        |   |-> src/com.example.*
        |   |-> tst/com.example.*
        |   |-> gradle-build-scripts
        |   |-> .git/
        |
        |-> ApplicationInterface/
        |   |-> src/com.example.*
        |   |-> tst/com.example.*
        |   |-> ant-build-scripts
        |   |-> .git/
        |
        |-> ForkedExternalDependency/
            |-> src/
            |-> some-other-build-scripts
            |-> .git/
```

Few things to note:

1. **Application** depends on **ApplicationInterface**
2. **Application**, **ApplicationInterface** depend on **ForkedExternalDependency**
3. **Application**, **ApplicationInterface**, **ForkedExternalDependency** depend on several external dependencies and share a few of them
4. All directories under `/ProjectWorkspace/src/` are respective individual repositories/packages with their own version control and build-scripts
5. Rest of the files & directories not within `/ProjectWorkspace/src/` are local workspace files and not maintained.
6. Project in IDE ( here IntelliJ IDEA CE ) is expected to be rooted at `/ProjectWorkspace`
7. If any of the package is checked out locally, I want to use them, else depend on remote release. ( ex: if **ApplicationInterface** package is available in `/ProjectWorkspace/src` I want **Application** to use it. If it isn't available locally in workspace, I want to **Application** to use dependency from remote-repository. )

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Hi @j-fabian-meier, I'm write a service code for hobby project. It has a main service package with multiple supporting libraries. I want to verify changes to the service when I make changes to dependent libraries too (manual calls and integration testing). The place I work at has a build tool to work in a way I've specified, but since my code is a hobby project, I'm looking for public alternatives to implement the behaviour.

Comment: Hey @JFabianMeier to add more context, the more libraries could include service-code, service-interface, dao, dao-interface, core, configurations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the tags I assume you have a Java project.

You should build it either with Maven or Gradle (Ant is outdated). Maven has a very good project structure, but you need to stick with it, not invent your own one.

If you need maximal flexibility, take Gradle. But have a look at Maven as well -- their idea to structure the project may be better than yours.